# How to add sub dropdown using materialize css?

Tags: html, materialize

I want to make sub dropdown using materialize css class dropdown-content.But following code is not working:

```
<a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1' data-beloworigin="true">Drop1!</a>
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">item2</a></li>
    <li id="drop2" ><a class='dropdown-button2 d' href='#'  data-hover="hover" data-alignment="left">dropagain</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="drop2" class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Item4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please add what you are expecting, what you are getting and what error logs/statements are being generated. "not working" is way too broad for anyone to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested dropdowns in materialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738599/nested-dropdowns-in-materialize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.dropdown-content {
   overflow-y: visible;
}

.dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
   margin-left: 100%;
}



<a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1' data-beloworigin="true">Drop1!</a>
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">item2</a></li>
    <li id="drop2" ><a class='dropdown-button2 d' href='#'  data-hover="hover" data-alignment="left">dropagain</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="drop2" class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Item4</a></li>
</ul>
```